# Embed opensearch dashboards without login page

Tags: authentication, iframe, opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

I'm trying to iframe opensearch dashboards in my website. Unfortunately when I add the iframe I am always landing on the login page rather then going directly to the dashboard itself.

With elastic i can enable anonymous users but with opensearch i can't find a solution to my problem.

Any idea?